# update client code in electron

Tags: client, electron

So I have multiple clients using an app built in electron. The entire application is actually a number of electron windows that talk to each other.  When I have an update for the client side code (html/js/css) I have to have them shutdown, and run a utility that downloads from our internal server to update their app.  I would like to know if there is a way I can either push new code to the clients (maybe through a socket) to overwrite the old code, or even maybe poll our 'code server' for updates, and then have it automatically update/overwrite existing code.

Is this possible? Is there functionality built in to electron that allows this?

And, if possible, how can it be accomplished? i.e. is there a library I can look at that will help me?? (i found a filesaver.js library, but its not exactly what I need). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your Electron app load all code from a server every startup and cache this locally. You can do this by simply hosting your electron code on a web server and pointing Electron at the URL. You could make the app work offline by using a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline/).

This isn't a great idea though as code loaded from the internet will have access to all the node APIs. You will have essentially made a DIY botnet and securing it from abuse can be tricky.

You should read [Security, Native Capabilities, and Your Responsibility](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) in the Electron docs and be sure you understand the implications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in autoUpdater of Electron: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater

You need a server the autoUpdater can talk to, to download the updates from. The updates are installed after download.

You can host a server by yourself or use a service like https://www.update.rocks/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is electron updater and you can use electron-builder for that.